# Gradle JAR - not exporting package

Tags: gradle

I'm creating a jar file using gradle that contains a single class file.   However, when I go to use my jar file I get:

> unable to resolve class pvx.core.util.DesEncrypter

on the import statement (running from command line or in eclipse)  If I create a jar file for the class from the command line everything is okay.  The only difference that I could detect between the 2 jar files - is the one from the command line has a MANIFEST.MF with permissions of 755 and the gradle generated has permissions of 644.

```
task utilJar (dependsOn:classes, type: Jar) {
    archiveName "DesEncrypter-${version}.jar"
    manifest { attributes "Created-By": "1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation)" }
    into ('.') {
        from "$buildDir/classes/main"
        include "pvx/core/util/DesEncrypter.class"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should rather be:

```
task utilJar(dependsOn:classes, type: Jar) {
   archiveName "DesEncrypter-${version}.jar"
   manifest { attributes "Created-By": "1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation)" }
   from("$buildDir/classes/main") {
      include "pvx/core/util/DesEncrypter.class"
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example that reproduces the problem?